# LAST_N_MONTHS:N in SOQL

Tags: soql, date-literals

Has anyone ever faced an issue with LAST_N_MONTHS:N in SOQL? As per salesforce doc:

> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the last day of the previous month and continues for the past n months.

Well the below SOQL works fine as it returns data for last 12 months excluding current month:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:12
```

But if run the below SOQL, it returns data for last 12 months **plus current month**

```
SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE ActivityDateTime = LAST_N_MONTHS:12
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: It should not. I just tested both the query by creating new account today and also by creating a new event with ActivityDateTime as today. Both the queries are not returning the newly created account/event record.

Comment: @abhisekSagar can you post a picture of your query results regarding ActivityDateTime query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's considering the date/time which is stored in the Database which is always in GMT.

> When viewing the record from within the Salesforce UI, the value is
>   automatically translated to and displayed in the timezone set on your
>   user record. However, when the data is inserted, updated, or exported
>   the values will always be in UTC or GMT time and are not translated to
>   the running user's timezone.

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(ActivityDateTime)) = LAST_N_MONTHS:12
```

It will convert the ActivityDateTime value in GMT and then will compare it to the Date literal. DAY_ONLY method is representing the day portion of a dateTime field.

Answer (score 6):

It works as advertised. However, bear in mind that times are transmitted in GMT, not local time, so it's possible to see some records that are 01-Dec-2018 in such a query for users with a negative GMT (GMT-00:15 or more). If you translate them to local time, they should indeed be in November.